# Compiler Error Message ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

When trying to run my ASP.NET program i am getting this error message below:

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.about_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnRunReports_Click' and no extension method 'btnRunReports_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.about_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Line 18 below seems to be the problem but i have no idea why.

```
Line 16:        </p>
```

Line 17:

Line 18: `<asp:Button ID="btnRunReports" runat="server" Text="Run Reports" onclick="btnRunReports_Click" />`
Line 19:

Line 20:     `<p><asp:Button  ID="IdSort" runat="server" Text="Sort" onclick="IdSort_Click" />`

On the run reports button i have this following code:

```
 protected void btnRunReports_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       RunReport();
   }
```

and then

```
 public void RunReport()
   {
       Application.Lock();
      // lb1 = (SaleList)Application["SaleList"];
       TextReportGenerator trg = new TextReportGenerator(saleList);
       trg.GenerateAllReport("report.txt");
       Application.UnLock();
   }
```

i have no idea how to fix this error, i have no errors in the .cs just on that line 18, some guidance would be much appreciated.

This is the About.aspx.cs

```
`using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.IO;
 using Antiques;
 using AntiqueSale;


 namespace Antiques

 {
public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page, ISaleManagerUI
{
    SaleList saleList;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(null, Session["ID"]))
            {
                Sale sale = new Sale((string)Session["ID"], (DateTime)Session["Date"], (string)Session["Location"], (double)Session["Picth Cost"], (int)Session["Num Pitches"],
                    (bool)Session["Charity"], (string)Session["Charity Name"], (bool)Session["Catering"]);

                saleList = (SaleList)Application["SaleList"];

                saleList.addSale(sale);

                Application["SaleList"] = saleList;

                UpdateListbox();
            }
        }
        catch (DuplicateIdException)
        {
           UpdateListbox();
        }
        lblerror.Text = null;
    }


    public void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.Lock();
            SerializeFileHandler sr = new SerializeFileHandler();
            Application["Antiques Sale"] = sr.ReadSaleListFromFile("data.dat");
            UpdateListbox();
            Application.UnLock();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            lblerror.Text = "Error: Not found, must save first";
        }
    }

    protected void Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    public void AddData()
    {
        var response = base.Response;

        response.Redirect("Default.aspx", true);
    }

    protected void btnAddBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddData();
    }

    public void getSale()
    {

    }

    public void UpdateListbox()
    {
        Application.Lock();
        lb1.Items.Clear();
        saleList = (SaleList)Application["SaleList"];    
        for (int i = 0; i < saleList.Count(); i++)
        {
           // ListItem lst1 = new ListItem(lb1.saleList(i).ToString(), i.ToString());
           // lst1.Items.Add(lb1);
        }
        Application.UnLock();
   }

    protected void lb1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateListbox();
    }


    protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (lb1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ListItem mySelectedItem = (from ListItem li in lb1.Items where li.Selected == true select li).First();
            lb1.Items.Remove(mySelectedItem);
        }
    }

    protected void lb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void SaveData()
    {
        saleList = (SaleList)Application["SaleList"];
        if (saleList.Count() != 0)
        {
            Application.Lock();
            SerializeFileHandler sr = new SerializeFileHandler();
            sr.WriteSaleListToFile((SaleList)Application["SaleList"], "data.dat");
            Application.UnLock();
        }
        else
        {
            lblerror.Text = "Error: You need to enter data into the list";
        }
    }

    protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveData();
    }

    protected void IdSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SortData();
    }


   public void SortData()
    {
       // var item = lb1.getItem(0);
       // var index = item.get_index();
       // lb1.reorderItem(item, index - 1);
    }

   public void RunReport()
   {
       Application.Lock();
      // lb1 = (SaleList)Application["SaleList"];
       TextReportGenerator trg = new TextReportGenerator(saleList);
       trg.GenerateAllReport("report.txt");
       Application.UnLock();
   }


   protected void btnRunReports_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       RunReport();
   }




}
```

}
`

Comment: just for kicks.  Could you please add the file names associated with each of the above code snippets?  ty

Comment: Do you have <% Page Inherits %> directive in your aspx markup?

Comment: Just one thing: are you sure if the aspx code have reference of the correct behavior code?

Comment: <%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="Antiques.About" %>

Comment: Please post the definition of the class, including the namespace.

Comment: Are you sure that DLL's were recompiled after you added the click handler in code behind?

Comment: is there anything else that i could let you know so that yous can help out

Answer (score 0):

Your Page Directive is wrong.  It needs to be something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Antiques.About.aspx.cs" Inherits="Antiques.About" %>
```

Comment: I have no Antiques.About.aspx.cs in my program, i tried that code and it says that it could not be found